# Assert a text box is empty in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I'm currently writing a test and I was wondering if there was a way to assert that a text box is empty.

The test is for a logout command that "clears data" instead of remembering your email or username. The way I modeled this test has the test log in, log out, and the part that I'm stuck at - asserting that the email text box on the login screen is empty after logging out.

I've tried stuff like this:

```
if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"text\"]").equals(""))) {
    // This will throw an exception
}
```

But that doesn't work because the arguments aren't accepted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to get the `value` attribute:

```
WebElement myInput = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"text\"]"));

if (!myInput.getAttribute("value").equals("")) {
    fail()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer works, but the assertion can be a lot cleaner.  Assertions should always give some reasonable message.  Here is an example using the JUnit assertThat and the hamcrest matchers.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.isEmptyString;
...
WebElement myInput = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"text\"]"));
Assert.assertThat(myInput.getAttribute("value"), isEmptyString());
```

Or better yet, give a reason message:

```
Assert.assertThat("Field should be empty", myInput.getAttribute("value"), isEmptyString());
```